# Angular repeat not updating when dragging between 2 sortable lists

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two arrays, where I want to dragdrop move items between one and the other.

We use angular and I'm just hooking up a simple link to jQuery sortable (because we also need to redorder).

When I move items around, the underlying scope arrays are changed, but the repeat is not updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/25gLp7r5/45/

This is the crux of how they are being moved, but the repeater doesn't show them.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  var id = $(ui.item).attr("data-id");
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list2.items.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.list2.items[i].id == id) {
      $scope.list1.items.push($scope.list2.items[i]);
      $scope.list2.items.splice(i, 1);
      break;
     }
  }
});
```

When moving the 2nd item from the top to bottom, it doesn't show, but is in the array.

Help! What am I missing?